# How to import module level functions into class instance in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
module AA
  def func1()
  end

  class BB
    def method2()
      func1()
    end
  end

end
```

Currently `method2` cannot find `func1` and raises an exception.

Why does this happen and what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that i follow is to include the module in your class definition

```
 module AA
   def func1
     puts "func1"
     end
   class BB
    include AA
     def method2
      func1()
       end
     end
   end
```

This is a Module Mixin strategy, works for any class outside or inside a module. 
Please read the Mixin section at: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html

Answer (score 1):

This happens for a couple of reasons.

Firstly, because things that belong to the `AA` module don't belong to the `BB` class.

Secondly, your syntax to define `func1` isn't quite correct.

See this example below of both defining the function (2 different ways) and calling it.

```
module AA
  def self.func1
  end

  def AA.func2
  end

  class BB
    def method2()
      AA::func1()
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the `extend`:

```
module AA
  def func1()
  end

  class BB
    extend AA
    def method2()
      func1()
    end

  end
end
```